# jQuery UI Accordion don't work with form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using the jQuery UI Accordion to develop a "wizard" form. I have four panels. Each panel contains a part of the form. The form starts before the div with acccordion instance.

**The problem:** If i click on the 'Submit' button, the form doesn't submit, as if the button has  "return false;", but i didn't add that. If i hide the jQuery UI Accordion, the submit button works properly.

Does jQuery UI Accordion disable submit buttons? How can I solve this problem?

[HTML on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/McPyfmi6)

Javascript:

```
// Accordion in Tags area
$("#accordionTag").accordion();
```

Comment: You might want to provide us with some code, esp. the HTML part. Thank you.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/McPyfmi6) :]

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look at it. Please consider pasting the relevant parts into your question too, so further generation of coders can reproduce it, even if the pastebin link should go down some day.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forget to generate a link inside pastebin.

Comment: [link for javascript](http://pastebin.com/dJBQMpnC)

Comment: I think we'll need either the resulting HTML output (that is: No PHP, but what the browser sees), or at least to know what you are using for the forms (Zend? Symfony? Something else)

Comment: Are you forced to use the accordion plugin? While I'm a huge jquery fan, the accordion plugin has limiting quarks and it may just be a better solution to write your own animate code so you have absolute control over what your "wizard" is doing in the dungeon (gaming joke) - just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

try coping your values to hidden fields in another form and on submit button click run a function which submit that hidden values form.
Hope it will work

Comment: Its a good ideia, but i'm waiting for other reply for this. If not, i will do this. =P

Comment: thanks. and if you pick this option don't forget to accept this answer :)